# Handling Boundary functions to determine Fourier coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

**Part I**

Let us say I need to determine Fourier coefficient at the end of the solution to a PDE. On applying the non-homogeneous BC, I arrive at the following

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\sinh(n\pi c)\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\bigg)=f(x)$$

We have two cases that needs to be evaluated now:

1. $f(x) = 2e^{-\frac{x}{3}}$
2. $f(x) = \frac{4}{3} (x-x^2)$

---

**Part II**

For $\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial y^2} = 0$ defined on $x \in [0,a]$ and $y \in [0,b]$

with the BC as

$T(0,y) = T(a,y) = T_a$

$\frac{\partial T(x,0)}{\partial y} = k_1\bigg[e^{-s_1y}\bigg(T_1 + s_1\int_0^y e^t T(x,t)\mathrm{d}t\bigg) - T(x,0)\bigg]$

$\frac{\partial T(x,b)}{\partial x} = 0$

---

For ***Part I***
After applying @Mattos suggestions

For $f(x) = 2e^{-\frac{x}{3}}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\sinh(n\pi c)\int_0^a\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{k\pi x}{a}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x=2\int_0^ae^{-\frac{x}{3}}\sin\bigg(\frac{k\pi x}{a}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x$$

The integrand on the LHS has values only for $n=k$ (From orthogonality)

$$A_k\sinh(n\pi c)\bigg(\frac{a}{2}\bigg)=2\int_0^a e^{\frac{-x}{3}}\sin\bigg(\frac{k\pi x}{a}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x$$

Since, $k$ is a dummy integer it can be replaced by arbitrary integer $n$

$$A_n = \frac{\frac{4}{a}\bigg[\int_0^ae^{\frac{-x}{3}}\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x\bigg]}{\sinh(n\pi c)}$$

Similarly, for $f(x) = \frac{4}{3} (x-x^2)$

$$A_n = \frac{\frac{8}{3a}\bigg[\int_0^a x\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x - \int_0^a x^2\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x\bigg]}{\sinh(n\pi c)}$$

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equality by $\sin(m \pi x/a)$ and integrate over the domain i.e \begin{align} \sum_{n \ge 1} \tilde{A}_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)&=f(y) \\ \sum_{n \ge 1}\tilde{A}_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{m \pi x}{a}\right)&=f(y)\sin\left(\frac{m \pi x}{a}\right) \\ \implies \sum_{n \ge 1} \tilde{A}_{n}\int_{\Omega} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{m \pi x}{a}\right)dx &= \int_{\Omega} f(y) \sin \left( \frac{m \pi x}{a} \right) dx \end{align} then check cases $m = n \ne 0$, $m \ne n$. Note that it should be $f(x)$ _not_ $f(y)$.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks . I have edited the problem to change the mistakes. Also, there was another problem I dealt with and would like to know what you think. Will the same procedure you suggested above work ? Should then I  have to expand $e^{-\frac{x}{3}}$ as some sort of series ?

Comment: @Mattos  I apologise, if i broke any community rule by adding a separate question to the same problem. If so please let me know.

Comment: A few things. First, did you manage to compute the coefficients for the two different functions? Secondly, where did the new equation come from (the one you edited in to your original post)? How was it derived? It seems a bit arbitrary. Third, what was the original PDE you started with? I'm guessing it is something like Laplaces equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: @Mattos Yes I managed to find those coefficients ,after reading your comment then relating it to trigonometric orthogonal functions. Yes, you are right I ought to post my worked out  solutions here

Comment: @Mattos As suggested by you, I have added the second problem governing equation and BC(s). Please have a look.

Comment: @Mattos Would it be more suitable if I post this as a separate question ?

Comment: Honestly, you need to stop asking the same question. You've made a new account now to ask the same almost the exact same question that you asked _multiple_ times on a previous account. In saying that, I'm doing the problem that you just edited out for you now, so undo the edit you just made to this post about 2 minutes ago and I will post an answer when I finish.

Comment: @Mattos Did you manage to handle the exponential term while finding the coefficient values ?I was thinking about expanding it as a Fourier series but that too leads to triple summation in some terms